# My Mac is not responding for this own IP, but it's ok for everything else

Tags: macos, networking, dns, apache-http-server, hosts-file

My Mac has the IP 192.168.1.123 and this network settings:

```
IP: 192.168.1.123
Net Mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.1.3
DNS: 208.67.222.222, 8.8.8.8
```

and apache answer correctly if I request `http://localhost` `http://127.0.0.1`

but if I request `http://192.168.1.123` it gives me a "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

If I do a ping to 192.168.1.123 it show:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.123
PING 192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.123 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.065/0.070/0.077/0.005 ms
```

If I do a traceroute:

```
$ traceroute 192.168.1.123
traceroute to 192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123)  0.181 ms  0.039 ms  0.030 ms
```

BUT! if ANY other computer do a request to `http://192.168.1.123` it show correctly!

The only weird thing I could found was that the previous user deleted this lines from `/etc/hosts`

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

I've already put those lines in `/etc/hosts` and restarted the mac... but the problem continue... any suggestions?

Comment: I found the problem, apache config was working perfectly. But the problem was with a service from [hide my ip](http://www.hide-my-ip.com/) it was blocking "internal" comunications, like 127.0.0.1 or the mac ip (192.168.1.123) so, after killing the service, the computer just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am changing my input to appease the jerks. So, make sure that apache is listening on that IP as well. In httpd.conf, add  `Listen 192.168.#.#:80`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help, but I recently found out that if connected to the same network you can also use http://computer-name.local

For instance, I have http://macbook-air.local and it shows Apache.

It's a lot more convenient, as your IP might change often...